# what is the ADA (Cardano crypto-currency) SDK?

Tags: sdk, blockchain, cardano

I'am very new to the blockchain community and I have a new project that i'am starting to work on using the Cardano Blockchain and its crypto ADA.
I stumbeled upon the name "ADA SDK" and I tried to dig deeper and research it more but i can't find any clear information on what do you use it for exactly.
I know what is an SDK in general but what is an ADA SDK ?
Is it the development Kit you have to download to start working with ADA ? or what exactly ?

I'am really confused is there anyone who could help me ? thank you !!

Comment: I can't find anything either. Where did you "stumbeled upon the name"?

Comment: This question isn't very clear, can you provide a link